# In Angular, What is 'pathmatch: full' and what effect does it have?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-router

In here it is use pathmatch as full and when i delete this pathmatch it doesn't even load the app or run the project

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './home/welcome.component';

/* Feature Modules */
import { ProductModule } from './products/product.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' }
    ]),
    ProductModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 157, accepted):

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
      { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: '**', component: 'pageNotFoundComponent' }
    ])
```

**Case 1** `pathMatch:'full'`:
In this case, when app is launched on `localhost:4200` (or some server) the default page will be welcome screen, since the url will be `https://localhost:4200/`

If `https://localhost:4200/gibberish` this will redirect to *pageNotFound* screen because of `path:'**'` wildcard

**Case 2**
 `pathMatch:'prefix'`:

If the routes have  `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome', pathMatch: 'prefix' }`, now this will never reach the wildcard route since every url would match `path:''` defined.

Comment: hello, thank you for clear explanation to this example, but can you give as another example with another type of routes to make it completely clear please ? (like using an example with children routes etc.. ).
thanks

Comment: really nice explanaton sir but can you tell me how to configure with 2 different layout.like inner layout and outer layout>

Comment: I can't reproduce the `Case 2`. Here is an [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-empty-path?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts) where I expected the first route to match everything but this is not the case. I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66941949/angular-router-empty-path) to try to have an explanation

Answer (score 221):

While technically correct, the other answers would benefit from an explanation of Angular's URL-to-route matching. I don't think you can fully (pardon the pun) understand what **`pathMatch: full`** does if you don't know how the router works in the first place.

---

Let's first define a few basic things. We'll use this URL as an example: **`/users/james/articles?from=134#section`**.

1. It may be obvious but let's first point out that **query parameters (`?from=134`) and fragments (`#section`) do not play any role in path matching**. Only the base url (**`/users/james/articles`**) matters.
2. Angular splits URLs into **segments**. The segments of **`/users/james/articles`** are, of course, **`users`**, **`james`** and **`articles`**.
3. The router configuration is a *tree* structure with a single root node. Each **`Route`** object is a node, which may have **`children`** nodes, which may in turn have other **`children`** or be leaf nodes.

The goal of the router is to find a router configuration *branch*, starting at the root node, which would match **exactly all (!!!)** segments of the URL. **This is crucial!** If Angular does not find a route configuration branch which could match the ***whole*** URL - ***no more and no less*** - it will not render ***anything***.

E.g. if your target URL is **`/a/b/c`** but the router is only able to match either **`/a/b`** or **`/a/b/c/d`**, then there is no match and the application will not render anything.

Finally, routes with **`redirectTo`** behave *slightly* differently than regular routes, and it seems to me that they would be the only place where anyone would really ever want to use **`pathMatch: full`**. But we will get to this later.

### Default (`prefix`) path matching

The reasoning behind the name **`prefix`** is that such a route configuration will check if the configured **`path`** is a prefix of the remaining URL segments. However, the router is only able to match **full segments**, which makes this naming slightly confusing.

Anyway, let's say this is our root-level router configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'products',
    children: [
      {
        path: ':productID',
        component: ProductComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: ':other',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'tricks',
        component: TricksComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: 'user',
    component: UsersonComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'permissions',
        component: UsersPermissionsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: ':userID',
        children: [
          {
            path: 'comments',
            component: UserCommentsComponent,
          },
          {
            path: 'articles',
            component: UserArticlesComponent,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Note that every single **`Route`** object here uses the default matching  strategy, which is **`prefix`**. This strategy means that the router iterates over the whole configuration tree and tries to match it against the target URL ***segment by segment*** until the URL is ***fully matched***. Here's how it would be done for this example:

1. Iterate over the root array looking for an exact match for the first URL segment - `users`.
2. `'products' !== 'users'`, so skip that branch. Note that we are using an equality check rather than a `.startsWith()` or `.includes()` - only full segment matches count!
3. `:other` matches any value, so it's a match. However, the target URL is not yet fully matched (we still need to match `james` and `articles`), thus the router looks for children.

- The only child of `:other` is `tricks`, which is `!== 'james'`, hence not a match.

4. Angular then retraces back to the root array and continues from there.
5. `'user' !== 'users`, skip branch.
6. `'users' === 'users` - the segment matches. However, this is not a full match yet, thus we need to look for children (same as in step 3).

- `'permissions' !== 'james'`, skip it.
- `:userID` matches anything, thus we have a match for the `james` segment. However this is *still* not a full match, thus we need to look for a child which would match `articles`.

  1. We can see that `:userID` has a child route `articles`, which gives us a full match! Thus the application renders `UserArticlesComponent`.

### Full URL (`full`) matching

#### Example 1

Imagine now that the **`users`** route configuration object looked like this:

```
{
  path: 'users',
  component: UsersComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'permissions',
      component: UsersPermissionsComponent,
    },
    {
      path: ':userID',
      component: UserComponent,
      children: [
        {
          path: 'comments',
          component: UserCommentsComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'articles',
          component: UserArticlesComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

Note the usage of **`pathMatch: full`**. If this were the case, steps 1-5 would be the same, however step 6 would be different:

6. `'users' !== 'users/james/articles` - the segment does **not** match because the path configuration `users` with `pathMatch: full` does not match the full URL, which is `users/james/articles`.
7. Since there is no match, we are skipping this branch.
8. At this point we reached the end of the router configuration without having found a match. The application renders *nothing*.

#### Example 2

What if we had this instead:

```
{
  path: 'users/:userID',
  component: UsersComponent,
  pathMatch: 'full',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'comments',
      component: UserCommentsComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'articles',
      component: UserArticlesComponent,
    },
  ],
}
```

`users/:userID` with `pathMatch: full` matches only `users/james` thus it's a no-match once again, and the application renders nothing.

#### Example 3

Let's consider this:

```
{
  path: 'users',
  children: [
    {
      path: 'permissions',
      component: UsersPermissionsComponent,
    },
    {
      path: ':userID',
      component: UserComponent,
      pathMatch: 'full',
      children: [
        {
          path: 'comments',
          component: UserCommentsComponent,
        },
        {
          path: 'articles',
          component: UserArticlesComponent,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

In this case:

6. `'users' === 'users` - the segment matches, but `james/articles` still remains unmatched. Let's look for children.

- `'permissions' !== 'james'` - skip.
- `:userID'` can only match a single segment, which would be `james`. However, it's a `pathMatch: full` route, and it must match `james/articles` (the whole remaining URL). It's not able to do that and thus it's not a match (so we skip this branch)!

7. Again, we failed to find any match for the URL and the application renders *nothing*.

---

As you may have noticed, a `pathMatch: full` configuration is basically saying this:

> Ignore my children and only match me. If I am not able to match all of the *remaining* URL segments myself, then move on.

### Redirects

Any **`Route`** which has defined a **`redirectTo`** will be matched against the target URL according to the same principles. The only difference here is that *the redirect is applied as soon as a **segment** matches*. This means that if a redirecting route is using the default **`prefix`** strategy, a *partial match is enough to cause a redirect*. Here's a good example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    redirectTo: 'not-found',
  },
  {
    path: 'users/:userID',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'comments',
        component: UserCommentsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'articles',
        component: UserArticlesComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

For our initial URL (**`/users/james/articles`**), here's what would happen:

1. `'not-found' !== 'users'` - skip it.
2. `'users' === 'users'` - we have a match.
3. This match has a `redirectTo: 'not-found'`, which is *applied immediately*.
4. The target URL changes to `not-found`.
5. The router begins matching again and finds a match for `not-found` right away. The application renders `NotFoundComponent`.

Now consider what would happen if the **`users`** route also had **`pathMatch: full`**:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'not-found',
    component: NotFoundComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    redirectTo: 'not-found',
  },
  {
    path: 'users/:userID',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'comments',
        component: UserCommentsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'articles',
        component: UserArticlesComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

1. `'not-found' !== 'users'` - skip it.
2. `users` would match the first segment of the URL, but the route configuration requires a `full` match, thus skip it.
3. `'users/:userID'` matches `users/james`. `articles` is still not matched but this route has children.

- We find a match for `articles` in the children. The whole URL is now matched and the application renders `UserArticlesComponent`.

### Empty path (`path: ''`)

The empty path is a bit of a special case because it can match *any **segment*** without "consuming" it (so its children would have to match that segment again). Consider this example:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'users',
        component: BadUsersComponent,
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: GoodUsersComponent,
  },
];
```

Let's say we are trying to access **`/users`**:

- `path: ''` will always match, thus the route matches. However, the whole URL has not been matched - we still need to match `users`!
- We can see that there is a child `users`, which matches the remaining (and only!) segment and we have a full match. The application renders `BadUsersComponent`.

### Now back to the original question

The OP used this router configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'welcome',
    component: WelcomeComponent,
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'welcome',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'welcome',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
];
```

If we are navigating to the root URL (**`/`**), here's how the router would resolve that:

1. `welcome` does not match an empty segment, so skip it.
2. `path: ''` matches the empty segment. It has a `pathMatch: 'full'`, which is also satisfied as we have matched the whole URL (it had a single empty segment).
3. A redirect to `welcome` happens and the application renders `WelcomeComponent`.

#### What if there was no `pathMatch: 'full'`?

Actually, one would expect the whole thing to behave exactly the same. However, Angular explicitly prevents such a configuration (**`{ path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome' }`**) because if you put this **`Route`** above `welcome`, it would theoretically create an endless loop of redirects. So Angular just **throws an error**, which is why the application would not work at all! (https://angular.io/api/router/Route#pathMatch)

Actually, this does not make too much sense to me because Angular *also* has implemented a protection against such endless redirects - it only runs a single redirect per routing level! This would stop all further redirects (as you'll see in the example below).

#### What about `path: '**'`?

**`path: '**'`** will match **absolutely anything** (**`af/frewf/321532152/fsa`** is a match) with or without a **`pathMatch: 'full'`**.

Also, since it matches everything, the root path is also included, which makes **`{ path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome' }`** completely redundant in this setup.

Funnily enough, it is perfectly fine to have this configuration:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'welcome'
  },
  {
    path: 'welcome',
    component: WelcomeComponent,
  },
];
```

If we navigate to **`/welcome`**, **`path: '**'`** will be a match and a redirect to welcome will happen. Theoretically this should kick off an endless loop of redirects but Angular stops that immediately (because of the protection I mentioned earlier) and the whole thing works just fine.

Comment: I am a bit confused for full path. you mentioned in Example 3 of full URL matching that `Ignore my children and only match me. If I am not able to match all of the remaining URL segments myself, then move on.`

Where as in full path matching of Redirect section you  mentioned `We find a match for articles in the children. The whole URL is now matched and the application renders UserArticlesComponent.`

From what I understood it should not match in Reidrect also?

Comment: For the record - I came up with the `ignore my children` explanation myself. Doubt this is how Angular developers see it, but it _is_ one of the principles of `pathMatch: 'full'`. So in the redirection example that you are referring to, notice that `pathMath: 'full'` is applied to the second route (`path: 'users'`), which, because of this, does **not** match. The matching route is `path: 'users/:userID'`, which does not use `pathMatch: 'full'` and works as usual. So it first matches `users/james` and then we look for `articles` in its children (once again, it does not use `pathMatch: 'full'`).

Comment: I got lost a bit in the `What if there was no pathMatch: 'full'?` section. Why it would create an endless loop if `/` matches `{ path: '', redirectTo: 'welcome' }` and redirects to `welcome` and changes URL to `welcome` at the same time? Why it won't render WelcomeComponent?

Comment: You might want to re-read everything starting with the *Empty path (`path: ''`)* section. An empty path (`path: ''`) *will match any segment*, so not only `/`, but also `/welcome`.  This means that after the URL is changed from `/` to `/welcome`, `path: ''` will match again : ] a bit weird isn't it? It's a special case in the routing system. I don't know why it was designed like that (never really gave it a thought, but it probably allows for convenient component trees), but that's exactly why one needs to use `pathMatch: 'full'` - it forces `path: ''` to match exactly `/`!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this so good and paying attention to the detail @Avius

Comment: I have bookmarked this. Thank you @Avius

Answer (score 105):

> `pathMatch = 'full'` results in a route hit when the remaining, unmatched segments of the URL match is the prefix path
>
> `pathMatch = 'prefix'` tells the router to match the redirect route when the remaining URL **begins** with the redirect route's prefix path.

Ref: https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects

`pathMatch: 'full'` means, that the whole URL path needs to match and is consumed by the route matching algorithm.

`pathMatch: 'prefix'` means, the first route where the path matches the start of the URL is chosen, but then the route matching algorithm is continuing searching for matching child routes where the rest of the URL matches.

Answer (score 10):

The path-matching strategy, one of 'prefix' or 'full'. Default is 'prefix'.

By default, the router checks URL elements from the left to see if the URL matches a given path, and stops when there is a match. For example, '/team/11/user' matches 'team/:id'.

The path-match strategy 'full' matches against the entire URL. It is important to do this when redirecting empty-path routes. Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop.

Source : https://angular.io/api/router/Route#properties

Comment: This explanation(among the ones given), in my opinion, is the simplest and easiest to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Default behaviour of Angular is: {pathMatch: 'prefix'} for all routes.

Now, let's see what is the difference between the two:

If pathMatch: 'prefix' => Angular will search for a prefix of the path(in the URL) in the routes array.

If pathMatch: 'full' => Angular will search for the exact path(in the URL) in the routes array.

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, the pathMatch: full configuration option is utilized in route definitions to instruct the Angular Router on how to match a URL to a specific route. When this option is set to full, it signifies that Angular should only deem the route as a match if the URL precisely matches the specified path. Simply put, the route will be activated only when there is an exact and complete match with the URL path.