# Angular 5+ routing parameter with keyword prefix

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I basically need to have a route like my-domain.com/property-123456 instead of my-domain/property/123456. The "property" prefix acts like the folder name. 
The app didn't recognise the below and redirected to the home page

```
  { path: '/property-:id', component: SinglePropertyComponent, data: { depth: 3 } },
```

Is it possible to do that in Angular 5+?

Thanks

Comment: remove `-:id` and in the wanted component subscribe to `this.route.queryParams` and check params

Comment: @JacopoSciampi but will `/something-123` match route `/something` ??

Comment: maybe you will have to use `pathMatch:prefix` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992212/in-angular-what-is-pathmatch-full-and-what-effect-does-it-have