# Parent Component Style Appearing on Every Page

Tags: angular, typescript

I took some code from another repository and decided to start my project using the already provided parent and child component in that repository. In the repository that I took there is a main component which is parent component while it's children are login, register and about component. Moving on, there is a navbar design in main component which is appearing on every other child page. The parent component is also the start up page so whenever I run the applicantion the main Component gets triggered. Now i need to design a homepage and I want that page to be the startup page and user should be able to navigate from that page to the other pages like sign in,register etc. But if I change the maiComponent to homeComponent in app.routing module then the homepage does appear in.startup but the navbar design disappears. If I make the homepage as a child component then how can I also make it to appear on startup?

app-routing.module.ts file

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { UserComponent } from './main/user/user.component';
import { NavComponent } from './main/nav/nav.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './main/about/about.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './main/register/register.component';
import { AddarticleComponent } from './dashbord/addarticle/addarticle.component';
import { DashbordComponent } from './dashbord/dashbord.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './dashbord/navigation/navigation.component';
import { MainComponent } from './main/main.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './main/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: MainComponent, children:
    [
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
      { path: 'login', component: UserComponent },
      { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent }
    ]
  },

  {
    path: 'dashboard', component: DashbordComponent, children: [
      { path: 'addarticle', component: AddarticleComponent }
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

main.component.html

```
<ng2-slim-loading-bar color="blue"></ng2-slim-loading-bar>

<div id="wrapper" class="animate">
    <nav class="navbar header-top fixed-top navbar-expand-lg  navbar-light bg-light">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon leftmenutrigger"></span>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarText" aria-controls="navbarText"
        aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarText">
        <ul class="navbar-nav animate side-nav">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Side Menu Items</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-md-auto d-md-flex">
          <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link"routerLink="" routerLinkActive="active">Home
                <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
              </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link"routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login
              <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
            </a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/register" routerLinkActive="active">Register</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" routerLinkActive="active">About Us</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
```

I need the home component as my home page but i want the navbar in mian component to appear on all components that are currently present and in the future components too. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If you need Home Page as a landing component, Give pathMatch as full for Home Component. 
  [Reference for PathMatch](https://angular.io/guide/router#set-up-redirects), [In Angular, What is 'pathmatch: full' and what effect does it have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992212/in-angular-what-is-pathmatch-full-and-what-effect-does-it-have)
- To have nav-bar in all the component, separate the nav-bar into a separate component and place it in app.component.html. Your app html should look like below.

```
<app-nav-bar><app-nav-bar>
<router-outlet><router-outlet>
```

Hope this might help.

Comment: it was that much simple. i guess my brain is not in working state. i need to sleep now. btw thanks for your help :)