# How to manage multiple routes in one lazy loading module

Tags: angular

This is site info routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '', children: [
    {
      path: '',
      component: WhyUsComponent
    },
    {
      path: '',
      component: WhoWeAreComponent
    },
    {
      path: '',
    component: WhatWeDoComponent
    }
  ]
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SiteInfoRoutingModule { }
```

---

Below is app routing module.The problem is that routerLink of all the routes go to the first component which is why-us in the site-info module.
If I keep the path empty in the app routing module and instead add why-us who-we-are and career-with-us in the respective paths in the site-info-routing module then it works but is it the best way to manage it ?

```
{ 
         path: 'why-us',
         loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule',

        },
     { 
     path: 'who-we-are',
     loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule',

    },
     { 
     path: 'what-we-do',
     loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule',

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not actually link your routes in the lazy loaded module.

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '', 
  children: [
    {
      path: '',
      redirectTo: 'why-us',
      pathMatch: 'full'
    {
      path: 'why-us',
      component: WhyUsComponent
    },
    {
      path: ''who-we-are',
      component: WhoWeAreComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'what-we-do',
    component: WhatWeDoComponent
    }
  ]
}
];
```

And the main routing module:

```
{ 
    path: 'site-info',
    loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule'
},
```

Comment: why is pathMatch: 'full' only in first one and not the others

Comment: If you want further information about pathMatch, please check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992212/in)

Comment: What exact route are you trying to access? The route should look like this:
localhost:4200/site-info/why-us

Comment: i was expecting  localhost:4200/why-us .. can we make it  localhost:4200/why-us no I should make different module for all these 3 components to do so.

Comment: `path: '',
    loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule' `works though

Answer (score 0):

This tells that whenever you get path `why-us` load `SiteInfoModule`

```
{
        path: '',
        redirectTo: 'why-us',<=== deafult loading path 
        pathMatch: 'full',
    },
  { 
         path: 'why-us',
         loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule',

        },
     { 
     path: 'who-we-are',
     loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule',

    },
     { 
     path: 'what-we-do',
     loadChildren: './site-info/site-info.module#SiteInfoModule',

    }
```

After that when module is loaded and corresponding routing module is loaded below:-

But, you are not specifying which component to load now as you have entered empty paths for all components.

So better provide some path here as well:-

```
const routes: Routes = [
{
  path: '', 
  children: [
    {
      path: '',  <=== default path can be empty
      component: WhyUsComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'whoweare',
      component: WhoWeAreComponent
    },
    {
      path: 'whatwedo',
    component: WhatWeDoComponent
    }
  ]
}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class SiteInfoRoutingModule { }
```