# Why Angular8 routerLinkActive sets Home and other links in the nav bar as active class at the same time?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to implement routing in my project. I have implemented navigation tabs. I cant seem to solve this below problem. Whenever i click on other tabs, home tab is always active.

I have tried to add routerLinkActiveOption, which everywhere is the working solution. But its not just for me.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
      <a class="nav-link active" [routerLink]="['/']" data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Home</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
      <a class="nav-link " [routerLink]="['/users']"  data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Users</a></li>
   <li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
      <a class="nav-link " [routerLink]="['/servers']"  data-toggle="tab" role="tab">Servers</a></li>  
</ul>
```

Routes:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path : '' , component:HomeComponent},
  {path : 'users', component:UsersComponent},
  {path : 'servers', component:ServersComponent}
];
```

[image: Screenshot tabs]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `routerLinkActiveOptions`

```
<li><a routerLinkActive="active" routerLink="product" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}">Shop</a></li>
```

Comment: You are welcome . Can you please give me a vote . If you got help full

Answer (score 0):

Your first route should look like this

```
 {path : '' , component:HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
```

Take a look at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992212/in-angular-what-is-pathmatch-full-and-what-effect-does-it-have) for explanation what pathMatch: 'full' exacly does.

Comment: Thank you for the response but this didnt work for me. I implemented @sourav solution and that did it for me!