# Partial matching to route to same component

Tags: angular, angular-routing

is possible to do something with Angular route like this

```js
    {
        path: 'my-',
        loadChildren: './pages/my-stuff/my-stuff.module#MyStuffPageModule'
    },
```

then when I navigate with different paths like my-orders, my-repairs.. this match with the same route?

thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42992231/6422273. This may answer your question

Comment: there is no examples to partial match like I need :(

Comment: https://angular.io/api/router/UrlMatcher. Yup! This one definitely works. Tested and  verified.

Answer (score 0):

You can use URL matcher function of Route object.

The matcher function returns UrlMatchResult Object or falsy value conditionally.

https://angular.io/api/router/Route#matcher

If you are going to use this, you can't use **path** field.

Here is an example to begin with. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular7-routes-5upyij