# Angular refresh/reloading the router is updating the url to default routing. How to stop that?

Tags: angular, routes

When I am trying to reload the url, the page refreshes to the default navigation. I want to stop that and reload the same url again. This is how my routing module looks like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
 {
  path: 'store', component: AppComponent, children:
  [
    { path: 'public', component: HomeComponent, data: { defaultSelectedTab: 0 } },
    { path: 'public/softwares', component: HomeComponent, data: { selectedValue: 'softwares', defaultSelectedTab: 0 } },
    { path: 'public/softwares/:id', component: SoftwareDetailsComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: "public", pathMatch: 'full' },
  ]
},
{
  path: '**', component: EmptyComponent
}
];

@NgModule({
   imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true, onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
   exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

I tried to do something like this where each of the independent path become a children of the previous one:

```
        { 
          path: 'public', 
          component: HomeComponent, 
          data: { defaultSelectedTab: 0 }, 
          children: [
            { 
              path: 'softwares', 
              component: HomeComponent, 
              data: { selectedValue: 'softwares', defaultSelectedTab: 0 }, 
              children: [
                { 
                  path: ':id', 
                  component: SoftwareDetailsComponent 
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { path: '', redirectTo: "public", pathMatch: 'full' },
```

But then this one doesn't even route it to the right component. I was trying to take a clue from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42992212/in-angular-what-is-pathmatch-full-and-what-effect-does-it-have) with the max votes. If in case it helps the router-outlet is specified in AppComponent. Still I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I believe your server changes the url. you can check if it is true in the network tab. just check the "preserve log" checkbox

Comment: I am trying to run it in local so, the files are getting served from local. The zuul configuration doesn't come into play.  Also, to confirm I made some changes and the routing seems to show a different url. I just added one more information that the router-outlet is present in AppComponent.

Comment: what is serving the files from local? angular serve command?

Comment: yes, the ng serve command is serving the files from local

Comment: most likely during refresh you have an error on some code executed. you should check the console for it

Comment: Please check whether you have added a routing statement in the ngOnInit() of first default component.

Comment: Maybe because of wild card routing configure, try to remove it and check

Comment: @KishanVaishnani - I have tried removing the path '' object. The issue that I see is that the first time when I try to load the specific path by writing the url in the browser, it loads but as soon as I click on refresh... it defaults to http://127.0.0.1:4200/#/store

Comment: @SwapnilSourabh: I can see that we are trying to get the data from activatedRoute, nothing else in ngOnInit

Comment: @SwapnilSourabh - found the culprit piece of code. Your clue was in the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei and KishanVaishnani too for your time.